# Manually register user with FormWizard and django-registration

Tags: django, django-registration, formwizard

I have a UserModel and a UserProfile Model and I would like to use FormWizard from the formtools to both register the user and setup a userprofile with necessary inputs from the user.

I am struggling with some concepts and trying to patch this together with no success so far.

I get the error message:

```
AttributeError at /accounts/register/
'MyRegistrationView' object has no attribute 'request'
```

forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'first_name', 'last_name')

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    course_accid = CourseModelChoiceField(Course.objects.all(), empty_label=None)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('picture','reg_completed')
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns = solid_i18n_patterns ('',
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', RegistrationWizard.as_view([UserForm, UserProfileForm]), name='registration_register'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
```

views.py

```
from formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView
from registration.signals import *
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.conf import settings

class MyRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
     def get_success_url(self, user):
         return '/index/'


TEMPLATES = {"0": "registration/registration_form_wiz.html",
             "1": "registration/registration_form_wiz.html",
            }

class RegistrationWizard(SessionWizardView):
    form_list = [UserForm, UserProfileForm]
    file_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/photos')

    def get_template_names(self):
        return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):

        userreg = MyRegistrationView()
        for form in form_list:
            if isinstance(form, UserForm):
                userreg.register(form)
            elif isinstance(form, UserProfileForm):
                userprofile = form.save(commit=False)
                user = self.request.user
                userprofile.user = user
                userprofile.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/index/')
```

Any help for what is wrong or if another approach would be better, is very welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not usually a good idea to call one class based view inside another view. It's even more unusual to try to call a specific method of the class based view (in this case `register()`). I would rethink your approach. If you need to use a form wizard, then maybe it would be best to duplicate the functionality of `register()` inside your `done()` method.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more why this is a bad idea?

Comment: The advantage of class based views is that you can subclass them and override specific parts of them. They're not designed to be used as building blocks in other views. Methods like `register()` are called by other views as part of a chain that ends with `dispatch()`, they aren't meant to be called by themselves.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you for the explanation!